# Need right-click on MacBook (Intel mid-2010) w/ Xubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: xubuntu, touchpad, macbook-pro

Command-Click on a newly installed Intel MacBook (Mid-2010) with Xubuntu 18.04.1 often fails; instead the Menu pops. I can't invoke a context menu to get to Properties and other functions. I have tried two finger clicking using a different distro (Mint), but hate it since I can't seem to accomplish it most of the time. How do I create a hot-key to give me right-click functionality? It need not use Command. TY.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for this :) Hopefully I am not too late.  I just got right click working with Debian 9 on a Late 2007 Macbook (3,1) but my reading suggests the same process should work in ubuntu. But had to come up with it myself, couldn't find it anywhere on the internet, just people suggesting alternative solutions like two finger click, or that I give up.

We will use xbindkeys to detect pressing the command and mouse button at the same time and xdotool to emulate a right click when this happens.

Firstly install xbindkeys and xdotool

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xdotool
```

Now we need to find out what the key you want to use with the mouse button to get right click is, 
Run,

```
xbindkeys -k
```

The last two lines should look something like this,

```
m:0x40 + c:37
Mod4 + Super_L
```

Note the last line, its what you need to make right click work.

Then create a file in your home directory called .xbindkeysrc

```
touch .xbindkeysrc
```

Edit the file and add this, (Add the quotes also)

```
"xdotool click --clearmodifiers 3"
  Mod4 + Super_L + b:1 + Release
```

In your case replace Mod4 + Super_L with what was returned when you pressed the key you want to use for right click.

Now reboot or logout (I just reboot to be certain lol)
You should find now that pressing the key you want results in a simulated right click.

If you using Gnome 3 and overview, keeps popping up when you press Command, install GNOME Tweak Tool (Not sure if its installed by default on Ubuntu) and under "Keyboard and Mouse" change "Switch between overview and desktop" to "Right super"
then you left command key won't open overview anymore.

If you'd like to swap you Left Control key with the Left Command key to get MacOS type copy, paste etc short cuts and Left Control + Click for right click then do this,

First, You need to swap the keybindings on those two keys in xkb. I edited my files directly

Edit, /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc

Find the part that has,

```
key <LFSH> {    [ Shift_L       ]   };
key <LCTL> {    [ Control_L     ]   };
key <LWIN> {    [ Super_L       ]   };
```

And swap Control_L and Super_L like this,

```
key <LFSH> {    [ Shift_L       ]   };
key <LCTL> {    [ Super_L       ]   };
key <LWIN> {    [ Control_L     ]   };
```

Make SURE you edit carefully, if you screw this file up your computer will just stop on a black screen without even reaching the login page and you'll need a ubuntu install disc and need to correct the file via rescue mode. (I thought I'd bricked my install)

Then reboot and check that binding is swapped.

Hope this not too long, I don't think I've answered a question before